# Using like statement in python 2.6

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to extract the names from the db that have A in the second position.
In sql it's simple but python sees the '_A%' as end of query.
Has anyone faced this problem before and came out with a solution?
I saw a similar question and the accept result was to use '% %' instead of ' %', but this didn't worked.
This is my query:

```
def queryDelivery(start_date):
    query_basictable = """
    SELECT Code,Quantity, Datetime
    FROM Mytable
        WHERE Datetime>= '%s 12:00:00' AND Name LIKE '_A%' 
    """ %(start_date) 

    delivery_data= pd.read_sql(sql=query_basictable, con=engine)

    return delivery_data
```

I was thinking about passing the symbol '_A%' to a variable and the do something like a substitute but when try to assign the symbol hits syntax error

```
 variable = ''_A%' '
    Name LIKE variable
```

How can I do this in a clean way?

Comment: Two percent signs is correct: `AND Name LIKE '_A%%'`

Comment: Nop -TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing

Comment: Your question contains no dicts or indexes, so I have no idea where that error is coming from.  Perhaps you could edit your question to include the full error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it this way.  As soon as you do this, if someone inserts a start_date like ["'; drop table students; --"](https://xkcd.com/327/) you have a problem.

I tested placeholders in Python 2.7 and it looks like you don't run into the problem until you use the `%` operator.

A much better way is to write your SQL statements in a way that every value passed in can be used in a placeholder.  Then use placeholder syntax and the syntax becomes `LIKE ? || '%'`